# Drawing Young tabloids

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices, parsing, ytableau

I would like LaTeX to produce output like the following

[image: example of a tabloid]

(without the 2 a so called [Young tabloid](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/12/11/young-tabloids/)), ideally by writing

```
\ytabloidshort{123,56}
```

(using one character per cell, ideally allowing groups via brackets as in
`\ytabloidshort{89{10}{\ldots}{n+1},56}`, but that is not important, the following is sufficient) or

```
\begin{ytabloid}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5
\end{ytabloid}
```

of course with arbitrarily many rows and columns. The command/environment must (also or only) work in *mathmode*. That's why I included the `2 \cdot` in the following examples.

I have found several ways to generate output similar to the desired, but they are all unacceptable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

perfect, but I do not see a way to remove the vertical lines while keeping the 
horizontal ones (ytableau):
\[ 2 \cdot
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
\begin{ytableau}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5
\end{ytableau}
\]

matrix (amsmath) and cline:
\[ 2 \cdot
\begin{matrix}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 5 \\ \cline{1-2}
\end{matrix}
\]

matrix (amsmath) and cmidrule (booktabs):
\[ 2 \cdot
\cmidrulewidth=\lightrulewidth
\begin{matrix}
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \midrule
4 & 5 \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
\end{matrix}
\]

tikzpicture and matrix (TikZ/PGF with library matrix):
\[ 2 \cdot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes] (m) {
1&2&3\\
4&5\\
};
\draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east);
\draw (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-2.south east);
\draw[red] (m-2-2.north west) -- (m-2-2.north east); % shows that lines don't overlap
\draw (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-2-2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

Two (and more) disadvantages remain:

- The output is ugly, actually unusable.
- They are all very uncomfortable to write.

What do you suggest?

Is it, for example, possible to parse the argument of `\ytabloidshort` and draw a matrix, each cell with content automatically with a line above and below. (But note the "problem in red"). How would one implement such a `\newcommand`? Any other ideas are also welcome.

I can split this problem into **three questions**:

1. How do I get tabloids whose appearance fits to tableaux generated with the package `ytableau`?
2. How can I make the result of (1.) work in connection with other maths, cf. the `2 \cdot`?
3. How can I generate (1.) in a comfortable way?

**Solutions** so far:

Ryan extented his package `ytableau` to draw tabloids. As long as your are using the package, this solves all three questions. The picture above can be generated by

```
\usepackage{ytableau} % version 1.3 or higher

\ytableausetup{tabloids, centertableaux}
\[ 2 \cdot \ytableaushort{123,45} \]
```

Sticking to the questions the status is the following.

1. Actually none. Spacing must be adapted.
2. Actually none. Alignment and spacing must be adapted.
3. Scott showed a way to generate the desired matrix by a makro. This is definitely worth noting and may be helpful in many other situations.

Comment: With a syntax like `\tabloidshort{123,56}`, how would one distinguish between the first entry meaning `1,2,3`, or `12,3`, or `1,23`, or `123`?

Comment: @PeterGrill: I think you can work with expl3 token list and clist. This simple as long as you have one digit per cell.

Comment: @Peter, Marco. Yes. I extended this part in the question a bit. But that's not the fundamental problem.

Comment: Hi Thomas, glad to see you here.  We've talked about this by email, of course, and I never did implement it.  Given its evident importance to you I will try to do that now.

Comment: That sounds perfect. It would complete your y*-package. Scott's solution works really well to produce the desired matrix. But I am already missing the `smalltabloids` option ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've expanded `ytableau` a little to include an option to draw tabloids.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
  \ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}
  $2\cdot\ytableaushort{123,45,6}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Currently the new version is [on my website](http://ryancreich.info/index.php?page=latex) and has also been uploaded to CTAN.

Answer (score 10):

The [`ytableau`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau) package (by **Ryan Reich**) could be an option (examples take almost verbatim from the package documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\ytableausetup{textmode}
\begin{ytableau}
a & d & f \\
b & e & g \\
c
\end{ytableau}

\ytableausetup{mathmode}
\begin{ytableau}
a & d & \ldots & f \\
b & e
\end{ytableau}

\[
\ytableausetup
{boxsize=1.25em}
\ytableausetup
{aligntableaux=top}
\ytableaushort[x_]{135,24,6}
+ \ydiagram[*(red!20) ]{3} \\
+ \ydiagram[*(blue!20)]{3,2,1}
= \ytableaushort[x_]{135,24,6}
*[*(red!20)]{3} *[*(blue!20)]{3,2,1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN mentions two other packages associated to Young tabloids: [`youngtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/youngtab) and [`young`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/young), but `ytableau` is the most flexible and customizable one, as far as I could see.

If you don't like the rules, you can suppress them by saying

```
\makeatletter
\def\boxframe@YT{0.0em}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

Comment: I feel honored that people are now hacking my package :)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina. Ryans package is wonderful for tableaux. Thanks for pointing out a way to remove the boxes at all. However, the question was how to remove the vertical lines while keeping the horizontal ones.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an option.  I'm not sure why you don't like the `booktabs` + `matrix` option, so you may not like this as well.  However, it should give you an idea of how it can be implemented.

**Edit 1:**  I removed a hardcoded value and added some of the booktabs constants into the function, you could fiddle with those to achieve spacing/weight that you like.

[image]

**Edit 2:** The case suggested in your comment should work now.  This still requires the first row to be the longest however.

[image]

**Edit 3:** Removed hardcoded displayed math environment because, well, it was a bad idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_body_tl
\int_new:N \l_first_row_count_int
\int_new:N \l_row_count_int
\int_set:Nn \l_row_count_int {1}
\cs_new:Npn \make_tab_row:n #1
    {
        \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \int_compare:nTF { \l_row_count_int = 1 }
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_first_row_count_int {\tl_count:n {#1}}
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\tl_count:n {#1}}
          }
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\tl_count:n {#1}}
          }
        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\clist_item:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {\l_row_count_int + 1}}
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {\tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl}
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_max:nn \l_tmpb_int \l_tmpa_int}

        \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {& ##1}}
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\\\cmidrule}
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {{1-\int_to_arabic:n \l_tmpa_int}}
        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_tail:N \l_tmpa_tl }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l_my_body_tl \l_tmpa_tl
        \int_incr:N \l_row_count_int
    }

\NewDocumentCommand {\tabloidshort} { m }
    {
        \heavyrulewidth=.08em
        \cmidrulewidth=.08em
        \belowrulesep=.65ex
        \aboverulesep=.4ex
        \clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
        \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \make_tab_row:n
         \begin{array}{*{\int_use:N \l_first_row_count_int}{c}}
            \toprule
            \tl_use:N \l_my_body_tl
        \end{array}
        \tl_clear:N \l_my_body_tl
        \int_zero:N \l_first_row_count_int
        \int_set:Nn \l_row_count_int {1}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\tabloidshort{12{10}5,1{\cdots}3,12}$

\[
\tabloidshort{89{10}{\ldots}{n+1},56}
\]

\begin{equation}
\tabloidshort{123,4,5,67}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 3. This version of `tabloidshort` is indeed pleasant to use. Thank you very much. I will look at this in detail as I have not yet worked with xparse. 
1. The appearence of the booktabs-suggestions does not fit to ytableaushort, it would at least require some adapted spacing.

Comment: It should be possible to make this suggestion even more flexible: Can the line over the 7 in `\tabloidshort{123,4,5,67}` be added, i.e. can `\cmidrule` consider the length of the following line?

Comment: I am going to hate you next year when I get the bug to overhaul my package, now that I am aware how efficient LaTeX3 is for this purpose.

Comment: @RyanReich It does make things surprisingly pleasant at times :)

Answer (score 4):

This was actually an exercise for me to learn [`xstring`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xstring) and [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) functions a little bit better so the end result is not polished and there is no optimization of any sort. Also there is a space on the left side when used inline. I can't see why.

The syntax is simply a comma seperated list which should be terminated by an additional comma otherwise the last entry is omitted.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring,tikz,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\youngtab}[1]{%
\def\youngrowlist{#1}%
    \StrCount{\youngrowlist}{,}[\rownum]%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\rownum}{%
        \StrBefore{\youngrowlist}{,}[\mynextrow]%
        \StrLen{\mynextrow}[\numlength]%
        \csxdef{rowlen\x}{\numlength}%
        \csxdef{row\x}{\mynextrow}%
        \StrGobbleLeft{\youngrowlist}{\number\numexpr\numlength+1\relax}[\mytemplist]%
        \xdef\youngrowlist{\mytemplist}%
        \let\mytemplist\empty%
        \csgdef{rowconcat\x}{}%
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\numlength}{%
            \StrChar{\csuse{row\x}}{\y}[\nextdigi]%
            \edef\mytemplist{\csuse{rowconcat\x}\nextdigi\relax}%
            \csxdef{rowconcat\x}{\mytemplist\&\relax}%
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\rownum}{
     \begingroup\edef\pfff{\endgroup%
         \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\mymatrixcontent{\csuse{rowconcat\x}\noexpand\\}}\pfff
    }%
    \tikz[baseline=(m.center)] {\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {\mymatrixcontent};
    \draw \foreach \x in {1,...,\rownum}{(m.west |- m-\x-1.south west) -- (m-\x-\csuse{rowlen\x}.south east)};
    \draw (m.west |- m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-\csuse{rowlen1}.north east |- {{m.west |- m-1-1.north west}});}%
    \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
    \let\youngrowlist\empty
}

\begin{document}
Spelling tableau \youngtab{789c,a3\%,45687,r,} correctly is very difficult so we populate this line with wise 
words to see the vertical placement. Then an equation follows: 
\begin{equation}
2\cdot \youngtab{1453,{\cdots}4,45687,6,68,}
\end{equation}
The rows are drawn but should it follow the the upper and the lower rows if they are longer, I don't know yet. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I think a `pgfplotstable` solution that is working inside a macro, should also be considered.

Comment: The options to the matrix and its nodes can be passed along with another argument to the macro.

Comment: My constructive criticism: I have long thought that if I wrote v2.0 of my package I would do it in PGF somehow.  Unfortunately, the strengths of PGF do not address the little things that need to be done for making this kind of diagram: keeping all the rows the same height, parsing the input, avoiding mysterious spaces...I don't know how to say this without approaching bad taste since I *am* the one with the package, but it's just not that simple to throw together something like this that works.

Comment: @RyanReich Sure, I agree about the tiny details that requires a lot of attention and this is not even a full working solution. I just wanted to see if it is possible with some concise construction. But still, coming from other direction,  I have to say that it can not be that complicated since it's just a table with rules.