# column tabloids versus row tabloids

Tags: ytableau

I'm trying to use the ytableau package to make tabloids that are column tabloids not row tabloids as in this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}
\ytableaushort{123,45,6}
\end{document}
```

[Drawing Young tabloids](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67139/drawing-young-tabloids)

Is there an easy way to delete the row edges instead of the columns edges?

In particular, I'd like to have an option for htabloids or vtabloids.

Comment: Or, even better, I'd like to be able to transpose the row tabloid as a single command so that it is easier to code, separating each column with commas rather than trying to figure out where each item goes in each row.

Comment: Your example does not compile. Please add some picture showing what you want rather than some link. I don't know `ytableau` and do not really understand your requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At some point I started drawing my tableaux using `tikz` because this is much more flexible. Below I'll put some code that draws the following three tableaux

[image]

using the commands:

```
\Tableau{{1,2,3},{4,5}}
\Tabloid{{1,2,3},{4,5}}
\ColumnTabloid{{1,2,3},{4,5}}
```

So the tableaux entries are entered by rows `{...}` with commas separating the entries. If this is want you are looking for then here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcount\tableauRow\newcount\tableauCol
\newcommand\Tableau[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,draw/.append style={thick,black},baseline=4mm]
    \tableauRow=0
    \foreach \Row in {#1} {
       \tableauCol=1
       \foreach\k in \Row {
          \draw(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)+(-.5,-.5)rectangle++(.5,.5);
          \draw(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)node{\k};
          \global\advance\tableauCol by 1
       }
       \global\advance\tableauRow by -1
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand\Tabloid[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,draw/.append style={thick,black},baseline=4mm]
    \tableauRow=0
    \foreach \Row in {#1} {
       \tableauCol=1
       \foreach\k in \Row {
          \draw($(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)+(-.5,-.5)$)--++(1,0);
          \draw($(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)+(-.5,.5)$)--++(1,0);
          \draw(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)node{\k};
          \global\advance\tableauCol by 1
       }
       \global\advance\tableauRow by -1
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand\ColumnTabloid[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,draw/.append style={thick,black},baseline=4mm]
    \tableauRow=0
    \foreach \Row in {#1} {
       \tableauCol=1
       \foreach\k in \Row {
          \draw($(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)+(-.5,-.5)$)--++(0,1);
          \draw($(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)+(.5,-.5)$)--++(0,1);
          \draw(\the\tableauCol,\the\tableauRow)node{\k};
          \global\advance\tableauCol by 1
       }
       \global\advance\tableauRow by -1
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \Tableau{{1,2,3},{4,5}}                \qquad
  \Tabloid{{1,2,3},{4,5}}                \qquad
  \ColumnTabloid{{1,2,3},{4,5}}   
\end{document}
```